# How to store (empty) allocator in my container without taking up size?

Tags: c++, allocator

I have an allocator aware container that has to store the allocator if it is a stateful one (e.g. polymorphic allocator). Otherwise, the allocator should take up no space. I thought the stdlib would use something like empty base optimization for this, however, I can't seem to get it to work:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory_resource%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+Allocator%3E%0Astruct+MyContainerBase+%7B%0A++++Allocator+allocator%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+Allocator+%3D+std::allocator%3CT%3E%3E%0Astruct+MyContainer+:+private+MyContainerBase%3CT,+Allocator%3E%0A%7B%0A++++using+base_+%3D+MyContainerBase%3CT,+Allocator%3E%3B%0A%0A++++T+myint_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++MyContainer%3Cint%3E+c%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22size+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+sizeof(MyContainer%3Cint%3E)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:54.49790794979079,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:45.50209205020921,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T, typename Allocator>
struct MyContainerBase {
    Allocator allocator;
};

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
struct MyContainer : private MyContainerBase<T, Allocator>
{
    using base_ = MyContainerBase<T, Allocator>;

    T myint_;
};

int main() {
    MyContainer<int> c;

    std::cout << "size = " << sizeof(MyContainer<int>) << std::endl;
}
```

Yields

```
size = 8
```

I had a look at libc++ and libstdc++ implementations of vector, but I couldn't find the allocator stored at all? It still works with pmr allocators though. How do I do this? Also, I must at least have some allocator object reference to use with `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>(myalloc);`

Comment: Specialise your base class based on `allocator_traits::is_always_equal`

Comment: You are storing your allocator in a base class but you not storing your allocator as a base class, so you aren't getting the benefit of EBO. Try `template <typename T, typename Allocator> struct MyContainerBase : public Allocator {};`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Good idea, but why not directly specialize on `std::is_empty_v<Alloc>`? And how do I access the allocator then for calls to `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate()` which needs an lvalue ref to an allocator?

Comment: @john Ah that's where I got wrong... How would i call 
`std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate()` in that case?

Comment: @glades Just `this->allocate()`. Dependent name lookup means `this` is necessary I think.

Comment: @john It would be a nice solution but I would also have to propagate the allocator if e.g. propagate_on_container_copy_assignment is true. I guess I would have to call base class operator=() manually in this case?

Comment: @glades You are getting beyond my understanding of allocators.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to C++20 this would require use of empty base optimization, but with C++20 solution is quite simple: use [`no_unique_address` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address):

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
struct MyContainerBase {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    [[msvc::no_unique_address]]
#else
    [[no_unique_address]]
#endif
    Allocator allocator;
};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:16,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:16,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:16,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:16,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory_resource%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+Allocator%3E%0Astruct+MyContainerBase+%7B%0A%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A++++%5B%5Bmsvc::no_unique_address%5D%5D%0A%23else%0A++++%5B%5Bno_unique_address%5D%5D%0A%23endif%0A++++Allocator+allocator%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+Allocator+%3D+std::allocator%3CT%3E%3E%0Astruct+MyContainer+:+private+MyContainerBase%3CT,+Allocator%3E%0A%7B%0A++++using+base_+%3D+MyContainerBase%3CT,+Allocator%3E%3B%0A%0A++++T+myint_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++MyContainer%3Cint%3E+c%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22size+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+sizeof(MyContainer%3Cint%3E)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:54.49790794979079,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:45.50209205020921,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: MS chose to delay proper support for `no_unique_address`  because it would lead to ABI breaking changes, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/#c20-no_unique_address

Comment: That's something I didn't know. Is it also possible to use this tags conditionally only when the allocator is in fact empty? In all other cases I wouldn't want to overlay the addresses.

Comment: @glades If it is not empty then it will take storage as usual.

Comment: Ok this was not really clear to me from cppreference. It means the class object will only not have an unique address in case it is empty, otherwise it behaves like a normal object? cppreference further says something like "tail padding can be used by other datamembers", which I guess would be an optimization even compared to EBO?

Comment: @glades If it is the first field then its address will be the same as the address of the owning object and its empty base, if any. Also if there are other `no_unique_address` fields then this object may share address with them. I think the only time one needs to care whether objects may share addresses is when their addresses are somehow used as identifiers.